# Angular dynamic key object evaluattion

Tags: angular

How could you evaluate dynamic string key inside object?

`{{ row["emails.email"] }}`

`emails.email` comes dynamically.

`emails.email` is a string

Like ag-grid, if you pass field in json

```
{
      "field": "emails.email",
      "title": "Email",     
},

Data Like
"emails": {
        "is_primary": true,
        "email": "dhiraj.pandya@ymail.com"
      }
```

On rendering it will evaulate to email value.

Comment: pass variable within square brackets without `quotes` `[]`  like `{{ row[emails.email] }}`

Comment: I have update my answer you need a method to get the data base of the  path

Answer (score 1):

you can create a method to extract the data from object base of path like this

```
 getData(o , path) { 
  let result =o;

   for(let p of path.split('.')){
       if ( result[p] == undefined) {
         return null;
       }
       result = result[p]
    }

      return result
    }
```

*template*

```
 {{getData(row,'emails.email')}}
```

this the pipe version

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'getValue'
})
export class GetValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(obj: any, path: string): any {
    let result = obj;

    for (let p of path.split('.')) {
      if (result[p] == undefined) {
        return null;
      }
      result = result[p]
    }

    return result
  }

}
```

*template*

```
  {{data | getValue : fieldPath}}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-path)

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand what you mean but it sounds like you wanna just do this to show the email:

```
{{ row.emails.email }}
```

Comment: emails.email comes dynamically. emails.email is a string

Answer (score 0):

I think you should apply an if check like:

```
<p *ngIf="field == 'emails.email'">{{ data.emails.email }}</p>
```

Mostly depends on the data you are trying to show. another case would be:

`let emails = {
    email: 'test@test.com'
};
{{ row[emails.email] }}`

Comment: As said above "emails.email" is a string rather than object.

Comment: can you please share the part of data structure which you are trying to show in interpolation so i can understand it better.